# How to set spark to use a specific number of cores?

Tags: apache-spark

I have 3 machines, each machine with 12 cores. How I can set spark to use the 12 cores?

In the spark-env.sh Im already setting the memory, but I dont find how to set the number of cores. Can you give a help?

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=28G
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following in your spark-env.sh on all machines

```
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
```

SPARK_WORKER_CORES specifies total number of cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine (default: all available cores).

In addition if you want two workers on single machine then try following :

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6
```

This will start two workers with 6 core each.

Check http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In your application you can sparkConfig.set("spark.executor.cores", value).  This refers to cores per-executor.

If you're using spark-submit you can also use options like --total-executor-cores , or --executor-cores .  If you're using yarn, you can also select dynamicAllocation.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im using spark-shell. But for example if I have 12 cores for each machine, I can set in each machine 12 cores. But you are saying to set spark.executor.cores 12, but I dont need to set any executor? The spark start executors automatically? But if set to each executor 12 cores and spark start more than 1 executor I will not have enough cores. So how I should configure this in your opinion? Hope you understand whay I said if not please say. And thanks again!

Comment: the options that work with spark-submit also work with spark-shell.  You can set cores per executor, or total cores, or if your cluster runs via yarn you can use dynamic allocation.  There's also a spark.executor.instances if you need to control the number of instances.  Check the docs, all the configs are documented.